# Trouble compiling a clickable QLabel

Tags: c++, qt

I want to have a `QLabel` in Qt which reacts to the mouse click event. I have found various similar solutions that don't seem to work in my current version 5.8.x

This seems to be the consensus on how to accomplish what I want: https://wiki.qt.io/Clickable_QLabel

If I take that, the program fails to compile with the error:

```
QtProjects/HelloWorldTest/qclickablelabel.cpp:5: error: undefined reference to `vtable for QClickableLabel'
```

(I renamed `ClickableLabel` to `QClickableLabel` because it makes more sense to me, the rest is 1:1)

I hunted down this error message and found the solution to just remove the `Q_OBJECT` macro, which in turn leads to this error which makes the least sense to me:

```
#ifndef QCLICKABLELABEL_H
#define QCLICKABLELABEL_H

#include <Qt>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QLabel>

class QClickableLabel : public QLabel {
    //Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit QClickableLabel(QWidget* parent = Q_NULLPTR, Qt::WindowFlags f = Qt::WindowFlags());
    ~QClickableLabel();

signals:
    void clicked();

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event);

};

#endif // QCLICKABLELABEL_H
```

.

```
#include "qclickablelabel.h"
#include <QDebug>

QClickableLabel::QClickableLabel(QWidget* parent, Qt::WindowFlags f)
    : QLabel(parent) {

}

QClickableLabel::~QClickableLabel() {}

void QClickableLabel::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event) {
    emit clicked(); // <----- Error happens here
}
```

Error message:

```
QtProjects/HelloWorldTest/qclickablelabel.cpp:12: error: undefined reference to `QClickableLabel::clicked()'
```

The `QClickableLabel::clicked` is defined as a signal and emit is for raising signals. So why doesn't the compiler find the method?

The existing solutions seem to be outdated, so a way to accomplish this for the current version would be appreciated!

Comment: How are you building this?  You need to run `moc` on `qclickablelabel.h` and then compile and link with the code it generates (having uncommented the `Q_OBJECT` obviously).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncoment the Q_OBJECT macro, the moc compiler needs that for the class.

if you are compilling using QMake, run qmake again so it will generate the moc files necessary to compilling the Qt code.

Answer (score 1):

Signal and slots are implemented in Qt using the [`moc` compiler](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/why-moc.html#code-generators-are-good):

> The moc reads C++ source files. If it finds one or more class
>   declarations that contain the Q_OBJECT macro, it produces another C++
>   source file which contains the meta object code for those classes.

You should be sure that `moc` processes your header file in order to generate the implementation of your signals:

- Add `Q_OBJECT` to your class definition
- Add the header file to your `.pro` file (assuming you are using Qt Creator): `HEADERS += qclickablelabel.h`